# Accompanying my wife (who is student) as a visitor

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, student-visas

My wife is going to start her studies in the US. We are both Canadian citizens, and I'm working for a US-based company, that has an office in Canada (so it's basically registered as a Canadian company)

I would like to accompany her to the US, and help her in finding a place, starting her day-to-day life, etc.

We both have I-20's, and I intend to continue working for my company (the entity that I'm working for right now) while I'm in the US for a couple of months. I read another thread where people suggested to no to mention that you work remotely when your are visiting the US.

Now I have a few concerns:

1. Will I have a problem at the border? when accompanying my wife? is there a chance that they say "you won't come back to Canada, because your wife is going to stay there for a long time, so you will as well?"
2. Should I go there as a visitor or with the I-20? Considering the COVID-19 situation I'm not sure they will even let me in as visitor.

Thanks

Comment: Given the closing of the land border, you (though not necessarily your wife) would have to travel by air.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you enter on F2 status (with your I-20), there is no problem with you staying for as long as your wife. If you enter on B2 visitor status, they might want to make sure you plan to return within 6 months.
2. Tourists cannot enter the US through the land border right now. People entering the US to attend educational institutions are exempt from the land border restrictions (e.g. see the latest rule on US-Canada land border restrictions [here](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2020/06/24/2020-13676/notification-of-temporary-travel-restrictions-applicable-to-land-ports-of-entry-and-ferries-service)), but I am not sure about F2 dependents of the student. There are no restrictions on B2 or other statuses entering by air. So you may need to enter by air either way.
3. Working remotely for a foreign company while in the US in a status that doesn't allow work (e.g. B2, F2) is a gray area. I can't give you any advice on whether this is allowed.